# GroupBy and apply different aggregations on columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
                  Time Call Number of Calls
1  2020-09-02 15:01:46    1               1
2  2020-09-02 15:01:47    1               2
3  2020-09-02 15:01:48    1               3
4  2020-09-02 15:01:48    1               4
```

I need to consider the Time column as a unique value and if there are unique values found get the count of calls. And for the number of calls showing using commas.

Ideally, the output as follows.

```
                  Time Call Number of Calls
1  2020-09-02 15:01:46    1               1
2  2020-09-02 15:01:47    1               2
3  2020-09-02 15:01:48    2               3,4
```

Comment: Super stuff,This is working

Comment: Hi if there is another column at last called 'cum' and If i need to get the last value of that column in group by how to do it,,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do a [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html), and aggregate with a `sum` on `'Call'` and with a `str.join` on `'Number of Calls'`:

```
df['Number of Calls'] = df['Number of Calls'].astype(str) 
df.groupby('Time', as_index=False).agg({'Call':sum, 'Number of Calls':','.join})

                  Time  Call Number of Calls
0  2020-09-02-15:01:46     1             1
1  2020-09-02-15:01:47     1             2
2  2020-09-02-15:01:48     2           3,4
```